# there exist a Universal Cache Middleware (bi-directional cache) between Database and Application?

Tags: mysql, caching, redis, bidirectional

Is there a **universal cache middleware** between database and application that can automatically **cache objects/entities when they are inserted/updated to database or queried from database**, and **return them to application instead of querying from database when they are already cached**? Or in short words, a universal bidirectional cache, illustrated as bellow:

[image: Universal Cache Middleware]

Already know that we can manually implement such cache for specific query. But can the coding be more general/universal? Someone somewhere might have done that; if not, what might be the best approach to implementing it?